# How to parse a list (array) input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, parsing

I am trying to solve a few problems using Python for arrays. However the input is being provided by the judge in the form of a list. 
Sample Input: 
[0,2,1,-3]

Now if the list was given as 
0 2 1 -3 
,it would have been easy to read the input and parse it to a list but I am not able to handle the symbols present in the input.
Is there a way to parse this list input to an actual list using Python?

Comment: Is the `list` that is provided a `json` compatible list?

Comment: you could do something like `[int(i) for i in input()[1:-1].split()]` or if it is json compatible just use `json.loads`

Comment: I recommend to show a working example code. Your Information "Now if the list was given as 0 2 1 -3" is very unspecific which data type is used. If they are strings the awnser is correct. But @user13915628 asumed that they are strings.

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve here..Do you need to get a list out of the input  where the input is a type of list or string or anyothers ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this if you want to read this `[0,2,1,-3]` input:

```
s = input() #[0,2,1,-3]
lst = s[1:-1].split(',')
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['0', '2', '1', '-3']
```

You can do this to convert the elements to integers:

```
lst = [int(i) for i in lst]
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 1, -3]
```

Answer (score 1):

if the input is a string and in the format of a dictionary or a list (mainly json  compatible) then you could try the built-in JSON package.

```
import json

inp = "[0,2,1,-3]"

data = json.loads(inp)
```

here `inp` is of type string and `data` will be a list. The structure of `data`  can change according to the input provided.

**Note:** this wont work if the input is like `0 2 1 -3`

Answer (score 0):

Use split. Here is a script that may help you.

```
a = "0 2 1 -3"
b = a.split(" ")
print(b)
```

The result is:

```
['0', '2', '1', '-3']
```

Comment: the question specifically states that is not how the input is given

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing input through cli like this

```
python3 script.py 0 2 1 -3
```

then,

```
from sys import argv
inputs = argv[1:]
print(inputs)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you trust the input you can do it like this:

```py
>>> "[0, 2, 1, -3]".strip("[]").split(",")
['0', ' 2', ' 1', ' -3']
```

If the parsed list should hold integers instead of strings then:

```py
>>> list(map(int, "[0, 2, 1, -3]".strip("[]").split(",")))
[0, 2, 1, -3]
```